# sql server using a case statement in conjunction with an in statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with 3 fields userID, state, country  and I am trying to run a query that finds all records where the country is Great Brittin, Canada or the US  and if the country is US I only want records in California, Utah and Arizona.

I thought this might work but no

```
select  *
from    myTable
where   county in ('GB','CA','US')
  and   case when country = 'US' then  state in ('CA','UT','CA')  end
```

Any SQL gurus have an idea?

**edit**
I think I tried to over simplify this. The countries and state are passed as variables so not sure if there will be a 'US' country but if there is there will be a state list

```
declare @country varchar(500)
,   @state varchar(500)
,   @sqlStr varchar(4000)

select @sqlStr = 'select * from Addresses
WHERE country IN ('+@country+')
OR (country = ''US'' AND stateCode IN ('+@state+'))'

exec (@sqlStr)
```

which makes this harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace the last line with something like that:

```
and (Country <> 'US' or state in ('ca', 'ut', 'az'))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are missing the `FROM Table` part on your query. In any case, this should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE Country IN ('GB','CA')
OR (country = 'US' AND [state] IN ('CA','UT','CA'))
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this

```
country in ('GB','CA')
or (country = 'US' and  state in ('CA','UT','CA') )
```